# Yii: Inserting database relations manually

Tags: php, database, yii, relation

There are 2 simple tables (MyIsam):

```
Child: 

    id(PK), 
    name, 
    land_id(FK)


Land: 

    id(PK), 
    name
```

These are the both Models (excerpt):

Following changes has no effects, if I modify the Models and let create the crud-forms, there are no changes and die land_id is getting no data from land table:

Model Child.php (excerpt)

```
class Child extends CActiveRecord
{ 
    ...
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'land_id'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Land', 'id'),
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

Model Land.php

```
class Land extends CActiveRecord
{
...
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'id'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Child', 'land_id'),
        );
    }
...
}
```

Where is my mistake ?

**EDIT: Do I need some more work, to get a select box with the corresponding land list in the created insert form (via CRUD) ?**

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

MySQL’s MyISAM engine does not support foreign keys at all.
Use InnoDB!

Comment: Try 'Land' instead of 'land' and 'Child' instead of 'child'

Comment: Does it make a difference?

Comment: PHP is case insensitive for the class naming, but if your operating system FS is case-sensitive you need to name your file with same case as in source code, so check capital and small latter in model because Linux server is case sensitive.